# Find the exact value: $ \lim _ {n\rightarrow \infty } $ $ \sum _ {k=1}^ {n} $ $ \frac {n}{3n^ {2}+2kn+k^ {2}} $

Tags: limits

I try to solve this question by using the L'Hopital's rule. However it doesn't make sense.It's seem to be 0.

I find that it is alaws decreasing so I know that the value is between 1/6 to 1/3.

But I still can't find the exact value

Comment: Can you rearrange the sum and view it as the definition of a certain definite integral?

Comment: What do you mean that you are using l'Hopital's rule? If you apply it to each term in the sum, of course it should be zero. Otherwise the sum is not convergent.

Comment: Hint: multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac {n}{k^2+2kn+3n^ {2}}=\frac {n}{(k-a)(k-b)}$$ where
$$(a,b)=-n\pm i  n\sqrt{2}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac {n}{(k-a)(k-b)}=\frac n {a-b}\left(\frac{1}{k-a}-\frac{1}{k-b}\right)$$
Using harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k-c}=H_{n-c}-H_{-c}$$ Replacing $(a,b)$ by their values
$$\frac{i}{2 \sqrt{2}}\Big( -H_{\left(2-i \sqrt{2}\right) n}+H_{\left(2+i \sqrt{2}\right)
   n}+H_{n-i \sqrt{2} n}-H_{i \sqrt{2} n+n}  \Big)$$ Using the expansion
$$H_{n+c \sqrt{n}}=\log(n)+\gamma+\frac c {\sqrt n}+\frac{1-c^2}{2 n}+\frac{c \left(2 c^2-3\right)}{6 n^{3/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

we should end, for a large value of $n$, and using one more term in the expansion, with
$$\frac{i \left(\log \left(1-i \sqrt{2}\right)-\log \left(2-i
   \sqrt{2}\right)-\log \left(1+i \sqrt{2}\right)+\log
   \left(2+i \sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}+$$
$$\frac{1}{12 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Simplifying the constant term (using the complex representation of hyperbolic functions)

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {n}{k^2+2kn+3n^ {2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cot ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{1}{12 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac {n}{k^2+2kn+3n^{2}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n
\frac{1}{3+2\frac{k}{n}+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}\\
=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{3+2x+x^2}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cot ^{-1}\left(2 \sqrt{2}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Mathematica without any integral sums in such a way.

```
Sum[n/(3 n^2 + 2*k*n + k^2), {k, 1, n}]
```

> `1/4 I (Sqrt[2] PolyGamma[0, 1 + n - I Sqrt[2] n] -  Sqrt[2] PolyGamma[0, 1 + 2 n - I Sqrt[2] n] -  Sqrt[2] PolyGamma[0, 1 + n + I Sqrt[2] n] +  Sqrt[2] PolyGamma[0, 1 + 2 n + I Sqrt[2] n])`

```
DiscreteLimit[%, n -> Infinity] // FullSimplify
```

> `ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]]/Sqrt[2]`

Comment: This is not the mathematica stack exchange. That is a separate community.

Comment: @NIradMunshi: Mathematica is aimed, in particular, to mechanize routine math transforms.

Comment: Very interesting way of solving it! I will try that by MATLAB.